# Why submit button still works in extjs even if email validation with vtype is failed?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Below is the extjs code for a window panel that has an email box and I used vtype:email to check for validation. The box shows error for invalid email but submit button still works. How can I throw an invalid email error when user clicks on the button?

```
    {
    vtype:'email',
    name: 'email',
    fieldLabel: 'Email',
    allowBlank:false,
    id: 'inviteEmail'
     },{
   xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Send',
    id: 'invitebuttonid',

    handler: function(btn){
    var email = Ext.getCmp('inviteEmail').getValue(); 
    var box = Ext.MessageBox.wait('Sending The Invitation..', 'Inviting User')
        Ext.Ajax.request({
         url: 'url',
               params:{
                   email: email
 },
            timeout: 300000,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(response, opts){
                var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                if (result.success === true) {
                    Ext.example.msg('Success',  result.message);
                    box.hide();
                }
                else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', result.message);
                }
            },
            failure: function(response, opts){
                var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed');

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your button to be automatically activated or deactivated according to form status, you need to add the config `formBind: true`.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Send',
    id: 'invitebuttonid',
    formBind: true,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check form.isValid() before submitting. Your bypassing validation by getting the value and making the Ajax request yourself.

Try

```
var form = this.up('form');
If (form.isValid()) {
     // your handler code
```